# Увеличить логотип

Tags: css, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Появилась проблема — на конструкторе нет возможности увеличить логотип в мобильной версии(чтобы на десктопе оставался таким же, а на мобильной версии был увеличен), пробую кодом, но не получается. Пробовал через инспектор кода поменять параметры в некоторых классах, но это не дало результата. Можете подсказать, что я делаю неправильно?

```
<style>
.cli-header-icon {
    max-height: 45px;
}
</style>
```

https://tx1008.craftum.io/ Вот ссылка на где нужно отредактировать логотип –

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не ту ссылку вставил, надо логотип Roxy

Comment: там где height допиши !important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
.cli-header-logo.iconed .cli-header-icon {
    max-height: 45px;
}
}
```

[image: max-height]

Comment: спасибо, помогло